# Django new URL not working

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to access a URL, `http://localhost:8000/calc`, but it gives me this error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    ^$ [name='home']
    ^calc/

The current path, calc, didn't match any of these.
```

This is what I currently have for mysite URL and secondapp URL:

```
 # mysite/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('firstapp.urls')),
    url(r'^calc/',include('secondapp.urls')),
]

 # secondapp/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url
from secondapp.views import CalcPage

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'calc/', CalcPage.as_view(), name='calc'),
]
```

Comment: The trailing slash is mandatory. Go to `http://localhost:8000/calc/`

Comment: ...or change it to `r'calc$'`

Comment: use` r'^calc/$'`

Comment: Neither of these worked. ^^; Whether I went to http://localhost:8000/calc/ or http://localhost:8000/calc

Answer (score 3):

As per the URL configuration you have stated in mysite.url and secondapp.url you link would be

```
localhost:8000/calc/calc/
```

which IMO would be confusing, if I am correct, URL you want is

```
localhost:8000/calc/
```

For that you have to change the url you have defined in secondapp.url to

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from secondapp.views import CalcPage

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'$', CalcPage.as_view(), name='calc'),
]
```

This would make the `ClacPage` accessible on

```
localhost:8000/calc/
```

See `/` is very important when defining URLs.

Answer (score 0):

use below reg-ex in urls.py

```
r'^calc/$'
```